# Problems to connect to ubuntu server in a virtual machine

Tags: server, ssh

I am not much experienced with ubuntu servers and ssh connections, but I would like to allow ssh connections in a ubuntu machine. I am trying to connect (ssh) to this ubuntu machine (which I setup in a virtual machine). That's the server status:

[image]

And these are the host info:

[image]

However I am unable to establish a connection:

```
ssh -X sudoname@10.0.2.15
```

> ssh: connect to host 10.0.2.15 port 22: Connection timed out

I guess I am missing something and I would be glad for any help.

Answer (score 1):

First Method:

USING BRIDGED ADAPTER

1. Setup your `SSH` in the host machine:

   - Open your terminal and run this command to set up ssh properly:

     ```
     ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 # generates ssh key so others know you, add values, but leave the default setup location
     ssh-add   # adds it to the client
     ```
2. Using `Network Bridged Adapter` settings:

   - Go to the `Settings --> Network` choose the device name, in my case `eth0`
   - Choose `Bridged Adapter` for option `Attached to`

     [image]
   - Note: no need to switch off or shutdown the VM it will pick up the new settings
3. Go to your Ubuntu virtual machine from the terminal run:

   ```
   ifconfig
   ```

   - look for the `IP` address associated with the network device (not `lo` device)
4. Now back in the host machine connect to Ubuntu virtual machine using the `IP` gotten in step 3:

   ```
   ssh -l <user_name_of_vm_user> <IP_address> #OR

   ssh <user_name_of_vm_user>@<IP_address>
   ```

Second method:

USING NAT ADAPTER

1. Setup your `SSH` in the host machine:

   - Open your terminal and run this command to set up ssh properly:

     ```
     ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 # generates ssh key so others know you, add values, but leave the default setup location
     ssh-add   #adds it to the client
     ```
2. Using `Network NAT Adapter` settings:

   - Go to the `Settings --> Network` choose `NAT` (which is the default)
   - Select `Advanced` option
   - Select `Port Forwarding`
   - Add the following to the table that appears:

     - Name: any name you like
     - Protocol: leave as is or change
     - Host ip: ignore
     - Host port: any number say 3003 (but not one already being used in host)
     - Guest ip: ignore
     - Guest port: 22
     - [image]
     - [image]
   - Note: no need to switch off or shutdown the VM it will pick up the new settings
3. Now back in the host machine connect to Ubuntu virtual machine using the `IP` gotten in step 3:

   ```
   ssh -p 3003 -l <user_name_of_vm_user> 127.0.0.1 #OR

   ssh -p 3003 <user_name_of_vm_user>@127.0.0.1
   ```

**Note:**

Free ports chosen if using firewall both on host and guest

[Virtualbox Networking](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html)

Answer (score 0):

In the VirtualBox > Machine > Settings > Network > Adapter 1

Select Attached to: Bridged Adapter 
and the name of your network card (it's probably already selected)